# Evaluate $\int_0^1{\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble integrating, especially since the question I am working on was not taught during the course.

The problem in general terms, integrate 
$$\int_0^1{\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Now, I have been checking the web for integration by parts but haven't come across any examples in this format.

So I put the equation in this form

$$x^4 (1 + x^3)^{(-\frac12)}$$

Now where can I go from here?

Comment: It really helps readability to format using MathJax. I started you off by doing the integral in the hopes that you could finish it off. See FAQ for more details on MathJax. Regards

Comment: I do not think your function has an antiderivative which is expressible in terms of elementary functions. If one needs the definite integral, a numerical method (Trapezoidal Rule, or something fancier) is the best bet. You can also find an infinite series whose sum is your integral.

Comment: Maybe it's $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^\color{red}{5}}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} dx$. That should be way easier, and can be done using Integration by Substitution. Are you sure you copied the problem down correctly?

Comment: @koloa If that is a homework and there is no error as user49685 say it is a cruel one. It is solve in terms of elliptic integrals. No simple solution.

Comment: See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E4%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E3%7D%7D%7Ddx&dataset=). I think there is no elementary representation of this integral.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ has nice Maclaurin series expression, so this integral has nice series form as follows:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\dfrac{x^4}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}\mathrm{d}x 
&=\int_0^1x^4\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n}}{4^n(n!)^2}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n+4}}{4^n(n!)^2}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n+5}}{4^n(n!)^2(3n+5)} \right]_0^1 \\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(3n+5)}
\end{align}

Comment: ... $ = {}_2F_1(1/2,5/3;8/3;-1)/5$